# How can I sort multiple columns at a time in Qtablewidget with ascending and descending order in Qt

Tags: qt, sorting, qtablewidget

I am trying to sort multiple columns in a QTablewidget at a time.
Also I should able to sort in both, ascending and descending order.
I try to solve this by using "tablewidget->sortByColumn(column, Qt::AscendingOrder);"
but it will sort only one column at a time.
Also it sorts only in acsending order. But based on user selection, I should able to select either ascending or descending order. 
Can any one help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How sorting by two columns could look like, in your opinion?

Comment: I'm not sure you can do that with `QTableWidget`.  A better bet would be `QTableView` with a custom model (perhaps based on `QStandardItemModel`) and a bespoke `QSortFilterProxyModel`.

Comment: QSortFilterProxyModel ?